# How can i convert html content(having images also) to a document file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to capture some content of a div in html (both text and images) and I want to convert that to a doc file so that i can mail it. I am using html5 javascript and jQuery.

I have to convert it on the client side.

Comment: If you only want to convert it to a .doc so you can mail it, I think you're taking the wrong approach to this.

Comment: @mark- In my app i am generating a report . The user has the feature of mailing that report in the app and according to the requirement of my client that report should be in doc .

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution http://www.phpdocx.com/. You'll need a server side language to do that, the example uses PHP.

Comment: thanx for the answer but I want to do it on the client side only.Is there any option for that.

Comment: As far as I know, no there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have such strict requirements:
Email the user a link with a version of the report you want the user to see when they open the doc.

Tell the user to open MS Word, Click File, Open, Then paste the link in.

The user can then save it as a .doc file where ever they want.

Note: By the way this is the wrong answer, Although you've already turned it down, slash197's answer is the correct way to do this and the way i would normally suggest.

That or just email the report as html.

Comment: I cannot use this approach. At any cost I have to convert it to the doc file

Comment: This will convert it to a .doc file. Once you open the web page in MSWord, click "File" -> "Save As" -> ".Doc". Why can't you use a server side solution?

Comment: since its a client requirement so we have to adhere to that.